# How to update regex to allow empty value or alphanumeric only

Tags: regex, coldfusion, lucee

I'm trying to modify a regex so it will allow an empty value or alphanumeric only.

I currently have this, but it only validates the alphanumeric

```
if (ruletype eq "alphanumeric") {
    bMatch = true;
    variables.fieldName = listGetAt(arguments.rules[nRow],2,",");
    if (structKeyExists(arguments.form, "#variables.fieldName#")){
        if (NOT RefindNoCase("[[:alnum:]]",arguments.form[variables.fieldName])) {
            lstError = listAppend(lstError,nRow,",");
        }
    } else {
        lstError = listAppend(lstError,nRow,",");
    }
}
```

I tried converting to rematch to find the `empty value`, but that also accepts the value `1234^%^&&` which contains special characters. I'm not sure how to fix that.

Comment: Alpha-numeric only and allow the empty string is `^[[:alnum:]]*$`

Comment: but when adding the one u gave @sln, it also verifies the value as: `test123%^&**&^&` - which is wrong

Comment: If the `^[A-Za-z0-9]*$` does not work, the code is wrong.

Comment: Which version of ColdFusion?

Comment: Lucee, its not ACF

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correctly, from the value you mention, that arguments.form[variables.fieldName] is a comma-delimited list? If so, then what is to be matched is each list-item.(Incidentally, the # in sdkfk364563!@#$% has to be delimited).

A possible answer is then:

```
if (structKeyExists(arguments.form, variables.fieldName)){
    // Assuming arguments.form[variables.fieldName] is a comma-delimited list
    fieldNameArray=listToArray(arguments.form[variables.fieldName], ',', true);

    for (fieldValue in fieldNameArray) {
        fieldValue=trim(fieldValue);
        if (fieldValue eq "" or REfindNoCase("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$",fieldValue) eq 0) {
            lstError = listAppend(lstError,nRow);
        }
    }        
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`[[:alnum:]]` is POSIX syntax, which may not be supported. Use the universal ASCII syntax, `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. Also modify your code to account for the presence of an integer and to rule out any possible space character.

```
 if (structKeyExists(arguments.form, variables.fieldName)){
        if (REfindNoCase("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$",trim(arguments.form[variables.fieldName])) eq 0) {
            lstError = listAppend(lstError,nRow);
        }
 }
```

Comment: btw i want to allow an emptyvalue to e passed and not validated, but the value is: `sdkfk364563!@#$%,` then it should fail